# How to find how many are not unique from a column in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a table net_advert with column customer_id. The column should technically be unique numbers. However, I will like to verify that. I want to find out whether all the customer_id are different and whether there are any customer_id s that are same and if so how many and which of those are?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT customer_id, COUNT(*) c
FROM net_advert
GROUP BY customer_id
HAVING c > 1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select
customer_id,
count(*) as tot
from 
net_advert
group by customer_id
having tot > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys

I ended up running the following mysql queries

```
SELECT count(*), count(colname), count(distinct colname)
  FROM tabname;
```

Comment: this query is going to scan full table 3 times.....not recommended, Abhik and Barmar's query is more optimized!! :)

Comment: This won't tell which customer IDs are duplicated

Comment: There's no difference between `count(*)` and `count(colname)` unless `colname` can contain null values.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT customer_id, COUNT(*) c 
FROM net_advert 
GROUP BY customer_id HAVING c > 1;
```